# Confusion about the use of unique key in mongoid db indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, indexing, mongoid, database

Let's say I'm indexing my user collection's email field as below:

`index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })`

The question is, what does `unique: true` specifies in above code.

Comment: It means that the index is unique on root document fields, i.e. you cannot do unique to a subdocument, it also means that any insertion into the index is sequential and atomic stopping race conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a variable to specify that the index specified is **unique** accross documents in a specific db

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html

from mongo docs

> MongoDB allows you to specify a unique constraint on an index. These
>   constraints prevent applications from inserting documents that have
>   duplicate values for the inserted fields. Additionally, if you want to
>   create an index on a collection that has existing data that might have
>   duplicate values for the indexed field, you may chose combine unique
>   enforcement with duplicate dropping.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Answer (score 0):

The `unique : true` statement here means that the index is Unique Index

By default, unique is false on MongoDB indexes.

Check the link for more details : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/